# SQLAlchemy Query - Python

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I am a little confused on SQLAlchemy and how queries work.  Let's say I have a table Team, and another table Games.  I set it up so if I do Team.games it will call up all the games Team has played.  Why is is that this works:

```
from table_definitions import Team, Games

blah blah
session.query(Team).first().games
```

and this fails:

```
teams_table = Table("teams", metadata, autoload=True)
session.query(teams_table).first().games

AttributeError: 'NamedTuple' object has no attribute 'Games'
```

??

And my second question is in the first query it returns this, `<table_def.Game object at 0x1b98090>` — how can I get this Game object to be a list of all the data saved in each entry?

Answer (score 0):

Hard for me to tell without the definitions of Team and Games. Obviously the returned objects are different.

It's probable that Team has a **table** property which would have the same properties as teams_table.

Here is an extract showing an example of a many to many relationship that might help.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Table, ForeignKey, Column, Integer, String, Float, Binary, DateTime, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

market_target = Table(
    'market_target', Base.metadata,
    Column('market_id', Integer, ForeignKey('market.id'), primary_key=True ),
    Column('target_id', Integer, ForeignKey('target.id'), primary_key=True )
)

class Market(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'market'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_market = Column(String(50))
    market = Column(String(50))

    targets = relationship("Target", secondary=market_target, backref="markets")

class Target(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'target'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id_target = Column(String(100))
    sort = Column(Integer)
    target = Column(String(200))
```